# setting a Markdown document with Ubuntu family font

Tags: ubuntu, r-markdown, font-family

How can I set the Ubuntu family font for this .html Markdown document, including graphics, in RStudio?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "23/10/2014"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the document as a whole, the easiest approach is to use the built-in `united` theme, which is based on Ubuntu fonts. Replace `output: html_document` with this:

```
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
```

R Markdown doesn't control the fonts used inside graphics objects, so you'll need to check the docs for your plotting library of choice to do that (here's a [guide for base R](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html)).